# Android: Showing users address and location in a widget

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude, street-address

I am trying to show users current address and coordinates on the screen, for example first it will show the coordinates and after couple of seconds it will show the adress of the user. But i couldn't do it. How can i do that ?

Edit 1: So far i am able to get the longitude and latitude of the user with no problem. Now i am trying to convert these to a street address, like city, street, etc. I couldn't find any good tutorial for getting the address from longitude and latitude, most of them is the opposite. So how can i get address from these coordinates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take two textviews, show latitude and longitude (coordinate) there by using textview1.setText(latitude+","+longitude)
2. If you want to wait for couple of seconds, you can use Thread.sleep(time).
3. Now show address in another textview by finding it from latitude and longitude.